# Trying to run private blockchain in console stops after successfully writing genesis block

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I am trying to run private blockchain `geth --networkid 100 --identity node1 --verbosity 3 --nodiscover --nat none --datadir=~/Documents/testmeteor/ init ~/Documents/testmeteor/Genesis.json console`. However after successfully writing genesis block console exits and node is not running. I run the command once, deleted everything except the keystore and allocated some ether to my account and then run the command again. Also if i try to run this command (since I need to connect my node to my frontend with web3API) `geth --datadir ~/Documents/testmeteor --rpcaddr="localhost" --rpcport="8545" --rpccorsdomain="http://localhost:3000" --nodiscover  init Genesis.json console` I get this error even though the `Genesis.json` exists in the directory `Fatal: failed to read genesis file: open Genesis.json: no such file or directory` Please help

Comment: _"However after successfully writing genesis block console exits and node is not running"_ - What was the cause of the first exit? What do the logs say?

Comment: Note that in the second command you are using a different path to the `Genesis.json` file (i.e. there's no path). Is that deliberate?

Comment: Nothing much.  `calculus@calculus ~ $ geth --datadir ~/Documents/testmeteor --rpcaddr="localhost" --rpcport="8545" --rpccorsdomain="http://localhost:3000" --nodiscover  init Genesis.json console` returns

Comment: `
I0314 17:52:47.437881 cmd/utils/flags.go:608] WARNING: No etherbase set and no accounts found as default
I0314 17:52:47.437975 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/calculus/Documents/testmeteor/geth/chaindata
I0314 17:52:47.491947 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:/home/calculus/Documents/testmeteor/geth/chaindata
I0314 17:52:47.492078 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/calculus/Documents/testmeteor/geth/chaindata
Fatal:failed to read genesis file: open Genesis.json:no such file ordirectory
calculus@calculus~$ `

Comment: Should the `init` path be `~/Documents/testmeteor/Genesis.json`?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. Tried it anyways but still got the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55360/discussion-between-petrosm-and-richard-horrocks).